# WPF splash screen UI not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I have a splash screen on my WPF application. The splash window is defined in my `App` class as a field, and in the `Startup` event, I perform various initialization features that can take some time, show prompts/windows, etc. My startup event looks something like this:

```
Startup += (_,__) =>
{
    mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component A...");

    InitializeComponentA();

    mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component B...");

    InitializeComponentB();

    mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component C...");

    InitializeComponentC();

    mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Opening application...");
};
```

For the splash screen update method, I have tried the following things:

- Using a ViewModel class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, binding to it, and updating the view model's `Message` property.
- Creating a `DependencyProperty` called `Message` in the code-behind, and binding/updating that.
- Setting the property directly (e.g. `myTextBlock.Text = splashMessage;`)
- Putting the splash screen in a separate thread and setting the splash message via `Dispatcher.Invoke()` (using `DispatcherPriority.Send` to ensure the UI is updated immediately).

My problem is that none of the splash screen messages are updating/displaying on the window. The **only** condition where the splash UI updates is when one of the `InitializeComponentX()` methods shows a dialog. In that case, the splash UI updates. For all of the options above, I have even tried synchronously and asynchronously waiting (via `Thread.Sleep()`) for a few seconds to see if the UI will update, but it never does.

Why is my splash UI only updating if I show another dialog/window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is my splash UI only updating if I show another dialog/window?

You're completely blocking the UI thread, which prevents WPF from being able to process and display your updates.

You need to move your work into background threads.

Comment: So, even though I tried moving the splash screen to another thread, it still won't update if I block the main thread?

Comment: @SpikeX You can't just move UI elements to another thread - the UI really needs to be updated in the main, UI thread.  You should move your other logic into other threads instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async and await mechanism to push the initialisation of the components to a workerthread. Something like this :

```
mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component A...");

await InitializeComponentAAsync();

mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component B...");

await InitializeComponentBAsync();

mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Initializing Component C...");

await InitializeComponentCAsync();

mySplashScreen.UpdateMessage("Opening application...");
```

It requires changes in the initialisecomponent methods that have to become async. But it should not be a very big update.
I also updated the method names to make them compliant to the convention that async methods end with 'Async'.
This frees up the GUI thread, and the updates should happen.

If you don't have this version of .NET yet you can initialise everything using a backgroundworker and user report progress to update the splash screen. Not too difficult I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, my application is .NET 4.0, I don't have access to `async`/`await`.

Comment: Then you need to push the initialisation to a backgroundworker and use reportprogress to sync up the splash screen